# How can I delete all Winamp playlists at once?

Tags: winamp

How can I delete all Winamp playlists from an Android device? I currently have to delete them one file at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long tapping on a playlist brings an option to delete. Looks like you don't want to use it because you've gazillions of playlists.

So, do this: Simply, clear data of Winamp from `Settings` ~> `Applications` ~> `Manage Applications`. It'll make your Winamp install fresh like when it was installed. The only thumbs down thing is that settings of Winamp will be reset to default & you'll need to re-configure them, but its not a big thing.

**Update:**
After some brainstorming, I found that Winamp stores playlists in a database externally. On my smartphone its: `/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external-xxxxxxx.db` where xxxxxxx are numbers which are different on two devices I checked.

Use Root Explorer to delete this database after mounting /data partition with R/W access (root access is required).

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened

Comment: @sultan Now, its interesting. :) Well, check my  answer update..

Answer (score 1):

I use the built-in mp3 Player (Samsung Galaxy S2).

I went into ***Playlists*** > *right button* > *Delete* > *Select all* > *Delete*.

Whatever the playlists were there, they will get deleted